# Морфологический разбор слова "полвторого"

Tags: морфология

Встретился такой вариант морфологического разбора:

Начальная форма: ПОЛВТОРОГО
Часть речи: Имя существительное
Грамматика: Именительный падеж, единственное число, неизменяемое, singularia tantum, средний род, неодушевлённое.

Это верно, можно найти указание на часть речи и род в словаре?

Я приду полвторого / к полвторого, сравнить: в пять / к пяти. Здесь "полвторого" - это В.п.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, это неверно.

В Современном толковом словаре русского языка Т. Ф. Ефремовой слова *полвторого, полтретьего, полдевятого* и т. п. - неизменяемые числительные.

Полвторого - это половина второго (о времени). Я приду к полвторого звучит, на мой взгляд, лучше, чем я приду полвторого.

Comment: Спасибо.  В принципе слово ведет себя как несклоняемое числительное, только я не могу найти информацию в словаре или в грамматике (у Вас не будет ссылки?). Употребляется с разными предлогами, только с предлогом В ( в значении  "когда") наблюдается вариативность.  ПРИМЕРЫ. На часах было полвторого.Я к вам не в двенадцать буду приходить, а в час или в полвторого. В полвторого она поехала к теще.   Полвторого ночи я постучал в дверь. Встал, взял будильник, накручиваю его на полвторого.Но до полвторого дня сидеть было просто невмоготу. Уложили вчера детей спать (еле утолкали к полпервого ночи).

Comment: @Sibylla могу предоставит фото словарной статьи из упомянутого словаря

Comment: Спасибо, я вам верю, мне как бы словарь скачать.

Comment: @Sibylla навряд ли вы найдете полную версию, но попробуйте. Вам подсказать какую-либо информацию?

Comment: Я пробовала воспользоваться словарем онлайн, но нужного слова  (полпервого, полвторого) не нашла. У вас есть ссылка на тот вариант словаря, где это слово точно есть.

Comment: @Sibylla Вот я про эту проблему и говорю :) В онлайн-версиях нет этих слов. Я поищу.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43772/discussion-between-aer-and-sibylla).